# While Loop, Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, while-loop, execution-time

I need to call the script function open() when the counter exceeds 5, but when I load my webpage, it shows me a fatal error : Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded. Is that my while loop problem?

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SELECT id, temp, hum, lum FROM weather ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

$weather["temp"] = $row["temp"];

$weather["lum"] = $row["lum"];

    $tempcounter = 0;
    while ($weather["temp"] > 27) {  
        $tempcounter++;
    }

    if($tempcounter > 5){
        echo"<script>open()</script>";
    }}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `}`, don't think that is the problem, but just pointing out that there might be more code that we don't see here,

Comment: What you want to do is not clear

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop is infinite. The loop will start if $weather["temp"] is bigger than 27 and inside you increment the tempcounter but never change $weather["temp"] so it will always be bigger than 27 and never get out of the loop.

You could put $weather["temp"] in a variable. Then inside the loop increment it also. But most importantly you need to reverse your condition. If you increment you need to check < and if you decrement you can check >.

If you increment:

```
$weatherTemp = $weather["temp"];
    while ($weatherTemp < 27) {  
        $weatherTemp++;
    }
```

If you decrement:

```
$weatherTemp = $weather["temp"];
        while ($weatherTemp > 27) {  
            $weatherTemp--;
        }
```

And then you can declare $tempcouter like this:

```
$tempcounter = $weatherTemp - $weather["temp"]; //Temperature needed to get to 27
if($tempcounter > 5){
        echo"<script>open()</script>";
    }
```

Code is not tested it might not work has it is.

If what you want to do is get the difference between 27 and your temperature you are not using the right logic here. You could simply take 27 minus your temperature form the query. If the result is negative just change it to positive and you get the difference.

Comment: How do i made update on the $weather["temp"] to get out from infinite loop?

Comment: I edited my answer with an explanation. Basically put the value in a variable. Then do the loop with that new variable and increment it in the loop. Then use that variable to get the difference in temperature.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is time over problem.

You can fix this problem by 2 methods.

1. Set max_execution_time to large value ex. 300 or larger
2. Begin of your php script call set_time_limit function

   set_time_limit(0);

Comment: I don't a query this small can possibly take more than 30 seconds. Also, there is an infinite loop. It would still get the error.

Comment: Yeah, I misfound this part.
You must change while ($weather["temp"] > 27)  to if($weather["temp"] > 27)

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
$tempcounter = 0;
while ($weather["temp"] > 27) {  
    $tempcounter++;
}
```

You're not updating `$weather["temp"]`, so it will loop forever if that condition is satisfied.

Comment: How do i made update on the $weather["temp"] to get out from infinite loop?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want your code to do. It's not clear from your question. If you want to count how many temperatures are above 27, you can move `$tempcounter = 0;` to the beginning of the code (above the first `while`) and change the `while` in my snippet to `if`. I can update my answer if that's the behavior you want.